# Как получить всю информацию о сообщении с почты(Imapclient)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, imap

Есть код,который выбивает ошибку ArgumentOutOfRangeException,но если  это imap.GetMessage(i) использовать вне цикла,то не выбивает ошибку.Как можно решить данную проблему.Я просто так пытаюсь получить всю информацию о сообщениях с почты(автора,текст сообщения,дату отправления)

```
 IList<ImapMessageInfo> infoList = imap.ListMessages();

                for (int i = 0; i < infoList.Count; i++)
                {
                    imap.GetMessage(i);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось очень просто.Нужно было передавать не i в функцию GetMessage,а UID сообщения.

```
IList<ImapMessageInfo> listMessages=imap.ListMessages();               
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
            {
               imap.GetMessage(listMessages[i].Uid);
            }
```